# NextJS AppRouter - how do i fetch /api/auth/me serverside?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I want to use app router using nextjs, and I've stumbled upon a problem. For my app to work correctly, I need to call /api/auth/me that returns a user or null if not logged in. For this, I need the axios api.get("/api/auth/me") to include an authorization header with bearer token taken from localStorage. I want to do this serverside, as I need my app to display google ads. How do I do this?

My layout.tsx looks like this

```
import "./globals.css";
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import Sidebar from "../components/Sidebar";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Create Next App",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="da" className="h-full bg-gray-100">
      <body className="h-full bg-gray-100">
        <Sidebar />
        {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

Comment: You can use localstorage if you go with client side. Are you able to do so, or are you limiting yourself to server side?

Answer (score 0):

You can not access localstorage from server side. However, you can use cookies. For security purposes, set http-only cookie. So, you need to make a post request after auth to set http-only cookie.